# Parse file name and path from full path

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need to parse file name and file path from full path using SQL Query.

**Eg. Fullpath - \SERVER\D$\EXPORTFILES\EXPORT001.csv**

```
FileName        Path
EXPORT001.csv   \\SERVER\D$\EXPORTFILES\
```

Answer (score 88, accepted):

Use this -

```
DECLARE @full_path VARCHAR(1000)
SET @full_path = '\\SERVER\D$\EXPORTFILES\EXPORT001.csv'

SELECT LEFT(@full_path,LEN(@full_path) - charindex('\',reverse(@full_path),1) + 1) [path], 
       RIGHT(@full_path, CHARINDEX('\', REVERSE(@full_path)) -1)  [file_name]
```

Comment: Why not just: RIGHT(YOUR_PATH, CHARINDEX('\', REVERSE(YOUR_PATH)) -1)

Comment: I have tested it and it seems sufficient. The only disadvantage is  that this works only if backslash if available in constrast to Path.GetFileName(path) in .NET

Comment: @StefanSteiger He did... he provided 2 fields instead of 1

Answer (score 22):

I do a lot of ETL work and I was looking for a function that I could use and [qub1n's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/518530/qub1n) [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33983085/100283) works very good except for values without a back slash. Here is a little tweak of qub1n's solution that will handle strings without back slashes:

```
Create FUNCTION fnGetFileName
(
    @fullpath nvarchar(260)
) 
RETURNS nvarchar(260)
AS
BEGIN
    IF(CHARINDEX('\', @fullpath) > 0)
       SELECT @fullpath = RIGHT(@fullpath, CHARINDEX('\', REVERSE(@fullpath)) -1)
       RETURN @fullpath
END
```

Samples:

```
    SELECT [dbo].[fnGetFileName]('C:\Test\New Text Document.txt') --> New Text Document.txt
    SELECT [dbo].[fnGetFileName]('C:\Test\Text Docs\New Text Document.txt') --> New Text Document.txt
    SELECT [dbo].[fnGetFileName]('New Text Document.txt') --> New Text Document.txt
    SELECT [dbo].[fnGetFileName]('\SERVER\D$\EXPORTFILES\EXPORT001.csv') --> EXPORT001.csv
```

Here is a [LINK](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0b728/2) to SqlFiddle

Comment: for me this IS the solution! ;)

Comment: This solution works even if a the field doesn't contain a valid path (not backslash, for example).

Answer (score 8):

Answer based on comment by Stefan Steiger:

```
Create FUNCTION GetFileName
(
 @fullpath nvarchar(260)
) 
RETURNS nvarchar(260)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @charIndexResult int
SET @charIndexResult = CHARINDEX('\', REVERSE(@fullpath))

IF @charIndexResult = 0
    RETURN NULL 

RETURN RIGHT(@fullpath, @charIndexResult -1)
END
GO
```

Test code:

```
DECLARE @fn nvarchar(260)

EXEC @fn = dbo.GetFileName 'AppData\goto\image.jpg'
PRINT @fn -- prints image.jpg

EXEC @fn = dbo.GetFileName 'c:\AppData\goto\image.jpg'
PRINT @fn -- prints image.jpg

EXEC @fn = dbo.GetFileName 'image.jpg'
PRINT @fn -- prints NULL
```

Answer (score 7):

Here is the simplest way

```
DECLARE @full_path VARCHAR(1000)
SET @full_path = '\\SERVER\D$\EXPORTFILES\EXPORT001.csv'
SELECT  LEFT(@full_path, LEN(@full_path) - CHARINDEX('\', REVERSE(@full_path)) - 1),
        RIGHT(@full_path, CHARINDEX('\', REVERSE(@full_path)) - 1)
```

Answer (score 5):

Here's a link where someone made several functions related to this need:

- CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetFileName]
- CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetFileNameWithoutExtension]
- CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetDirectoryPath]
- CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetExtension]

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/866934/Extracting-the-filename-from-a-full-path-in-SQL-Se?msg=5145303#xx5145303xx

Answer (score 3):

How about:

`reverse(LEFT(REVERSE(FileName),
 Coalesce(nullif(CHARINDEX('\', REVERSE(FileName))-1, -1), len(FileName))
 ))`

Weird, I know, but it means I can avoid the no `\` issue and still do it inline.

Answer (score 2):

Using `REVERSE` is easier to see

```
DECLARE @full_path VARCHAR(1000)
SET @full_path = '\\SERVER\D$\EXPORTFILES\EXPORT001.csv'

select REVERSE(LEFT(REVERSE(@full_path),CHARINDEX( '\',REVERSE(@full_path))-1)) as [FileName],
       replace(@full_path, REVERSE(LEFT(REVERSE(@full_path),CHARINDEX( '\',REVERSE(@full_path))-1)),'') as [FilePath]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Declare @filepath Nvarchar(1000)
Set @filepath = 'D:\ABCD\HIJK\MYFILE.TXT'

    --Using Left and Right
    Select LEFT(@filepath,LEN(@filePath)-CHARINDEX('\',REVERSE(@filepath))+1) Path,
        RIGHT(@filepath,CHARINDEX('\',REVERSE(@filepath))-1) FileName

    -- Using Substring      
    Select SUBSTRING(@filepath,1,LEN(@filepath)-CHARINDEX('\',REVERSE(@filepath))+1) Path,
        REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(@filepath),1,CHARINDEX('\',REVERSE(@filepath))-1)) FileName
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
LTRIM(
RTRIM(
REVERSE(
SUBSTRING(
REVERSE(Filename),0,CHARINDEX('\',REVERSE(Filename),0))
)))
 from TblFilePath
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that wants to perform this operation and also trim off the file extension:

```
SELECT
    LEFT(
        RIGHT(<FIELD>, CHARINDEX('\', REVERSE(<FIELD>)) - 1),
        LEN(RIGHT(<FIELD>, CHARINDEX('\', REVERSE(<FIELD>)) - 1)) -
          CHARINDEX('.', REVERSE(<FIELD>))
    )
FROM <TABLE>
```

Note that this doesn't allow for when there are no slashes - it will need modification if this is the case