# Removing folder path and extension from SQL column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have done some research, but I have been unable to do/find how to put the two together.

I am trying to get the filename from a field known as doc_filename, minus any document path and extension, for example `"docs\00010\filename.doc"` should be just be `"filename"`.

This has worked to remove the path name, however the extension remains. How do I remove this?

Thanks

```
SELECT (case when doc_filename like '%\%' then 
 LTRIM(
  RTRIM(
   REVERSE(
    SUBSTRING(
     REVERSE(doc_filename),0, CHARINDEX('\', REVERSE(doc_filename),0)
    )
   )
  )
 )
 else ''
 end)

FROM documents
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse file name and path from full path](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19505875/parse-file-name-and-path-from-full-path)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By way of an example:

```
DECLARE @fps TABLE(fp VARCHAR(512));
INSERT INTO @fps(fp)VALUES
    ('\filename.001.doc'),
    ('docs\00010\filename.doc'),
    ('docs\00010\filename'),
    ('filename.doc'),
    ('filename'),
    ('\filename'),
    ('\filename.001.doc'); 
    -- ('.\filename'); --> this one will fail

SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN CHARINDEX('.',REVERSE(fp))=0 AND CHARINDEX('\',REVERSE(fp))=0 THEN fp
        WHEN CHARINDEX('.',REVERSE(fp))=0 THEN RIGHT(fp,CHARINDEX('\',REVERSE(fp))-1)
        WHEN CHARINDEX('\',REVERSE(fp))=0 THEN LEFT(fp,LEN(fp)-CHARINDEX('.',REVERSE(fp)))
        ELSE SUBSTRING(fp,LEN(fp)-CHARINDEX('\',REVERSE(fp))+2,CHARINDEX('\',REVERSE(fp))-CHARINDEX('.',REVERSE(fp))-1)
    END AS [file_name]
FROM
    @fps;
```

Result:

```
+--------------+
|  file_name   |
+--------------+
| filename.001 |
| filename     |
| filename     |
| filename     |
| filename     |
| filename     |
| filename.001 |
+--------------+
```

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you.