# stripping just the filename from a string in sql by looking at the '/' dash character

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, ssis-2012

I would like to know how to accomplish getting just the file name from the below

```
C:\Users\avs\Desktop\Testing\Text Files\TargetFolder\PN005337.RCS
```

the PN005337.RCS file name can vary in name and length. However the only definitive way of capturing it would be looking at the last '\' and then bringing back any thing after the very last '\'.

Anyway to do that in sql. This is a column in sql server, but the report owner just wants to see the name.

I am doing this in SSIS so either solution would be great in an expression or in SQL.

Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse file name and path from full path](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19505875/parse-file-name-and-path-from-full-path)

Answer (score 1):

You could determine the index of the last slash by first `REVERSE` the path and then find the slash by means of `CHARINDEX`.
Finally you extract the filename applying to the original path the function `RIGHT` using the found index.

The expression would be `RIGHT(path, CHARINDEX('/', REVERSE(path)) - 1)`

Comment: Thank you Robert, this gives me exactly what I need to know. Any chance you can give it in SSIS as en expression just for my benefit as well?

Comment: Sorry in SSIS,  as charindex isnt an option in SSIS expression

Comment: It's been years the last time I used SSIS. Sorry about that.

Comment: No worries,  this gives it what i want anyway

Answer (score 0):

A case for CROSS APPLY to make intermediate computations

```
declare @t table (full_path varchar(max));
insert @t values 
 ('C:\Users\avs\Desktop\Testing\Text Files\TargetFolder\PN005337.RCS'), 
 ('C:PN005337.RCS'), 
 ('PN005337.RCS');


SELECT full_path, 
    CASE WHEN pback>=0 THEN RIGHT(full_path, pback) 
         WHEN pcol>=0 THEN RIGHT(full_path, pcol) 
         ELSE full_path
         END as fname
FROM  @t
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT pback= CHARINDEX('\', REVERSE(full_path)) -1, pCol = CHARINDEX(':', REVERSE(full_path)) -1
    ) pp
```