# How can I extract the file name from a file path

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to extract the file name given a variable file path. Some path examples:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\CentralDB.mdf

C:\MSSQL\DATA\CentralDB.mdf

C:\DATA\CentralDB.mdf
```

Expected Out put should be only the file names, i.e:

`CentralDb.mdf`
`CentralDB.ldf`

The file path length can vary form location to location.

Comment: [How do I ask a **good** question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  - your question lacks any kind of context, explanation of what you're trying to do - very unclear, very confusing - you need to improve this !

Comment: It's very unclear....what you want to achieve...you want to create a sql function that receives a path and returns just the mdf filename?

Comment: `DECLARE @t TABLE(
   val VARCHAR(8000)    
);
INSERT INTO @t(val)VALUES('C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\CentralDB.mdf');
INSERT INTO @t(val)VALUES('C:\MSSQL\DATA\CentralDB.mdf');
INSERT INTO @t(val)VALUES('C:\DATA\CentralDB.mdf');

SELECT
    RIGHT(val,CHARINDEX('\',REVERSE(val))-1)
FROM
    @t;`

Comment: I think you are looking for this. `Select RIGHT(physical_name,CHARINDEX('\',REVERSE(physical_name))-1) From Sys.database_files`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19505875/parse-file-name-and-path-from-full-path

Answer (score 7):

You can use the reverse of the string to find the first '\' and then take the RIGHT value of that.

```
declare @var varchar(4000)

set @var = 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\CentralDB.mdf'
select RIGHT(@var,CHARINDEX('\',REVERSE(@var))-1)

set @var = 'C:\DATA\CentralDB.mdf'
select RIGHT(@var,CHARINDEX('\',REVERSE(@var))-1)

set @var = 'C:\MSSQL\DATA\CentralDB.mdf'
select RIGHT(@var,CHARINDEX('\',REVERSE(@var))-1)
```

Comment: Using your example. `Select RIGHT(physical_name,CHARINDEX('\',REVERSE(physical_name))-1)
    From Sys.database_files`

Comment: It worked fine :-)